# Regex works, but not on strings in my vector

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, stringr

So I am attempting to use grep to find pattern and replace values within my single column data frame. I basically want grep that says "delete everything after the comma until the end of the string". 
I wrote the expression, and it works on my dummy vector:

```
> library(stringr)
> pretendvector <- c("Hi","Hi,there","Hi there, how are you")
>str_replace(pretendvector, regex(',.*$'),'')
[1] "Hi"       "Hi"       "Hi there"
```

However, when apply the same expression to my vector (since its for stringr I vectorized the column of the dataframe), it returns every value in the column, and does not apply the expression. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: It is not clear what you meant by `it return every value in the column` did you assign the output to some object? i.e. `newvector <- str_replace(pretendvector, regex(',.*$'),'')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the OP didn't assign the output from `str_replace` to a new object or update the original vector.  In that case,

```
newvector <- str_replace(pretendvector, regex(',.*$'),'')
```

We can also do this using `sub` from `base R`

```
newvector <- sub(",.*", "", pretendvector)
```